# Homework: warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format [-Wformat=]

Tags: c, linux, macos

I'm getting the above warning when I run this code. I'm a little uncertain, because it works fine in a mac OS environment, but as soon as I run it in linux, it stops working.

```
while(sscanf(page.ptr, "%[^\n]\n%[^\0]", currline, page.ptr) == 2)
{
...
}
```

These are the other warnings I get on the Linux system:

```
weather.c: In function ‘main’:
weather.c:121:9: warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format [-Wformat=]
     while(sscanf(page.ptr, "%[^\n]\n%[^\0]", currline, page.ptr) == 2)
     ^
weather.c:121:9: warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format [-Wformat-contains-nul]
```

Can anyone explain to me why this would be different on the two systems, and why it wouldn't work on this system? Or what I should consider to correct this warning?

Comment: C strings end at the `\0` character. Anything after that is ignored.

Comment: OS X has a different compiler from Linux, and they generate different warnings.

Comment: Yeah, but then it shouldn't work on Mac OS, and it does.

Comment: Just because you don't get an warning doesn't mean that it works correctly.

Comment: `clang`, the default compiler on OS X, tends to be a bit stricter (and better) at giving warnings than `gcc`

Comment: @sapi, I'm using gcc on both. (I have a makefile I can put up), wouldn't it be using the same compiler? and wouldn't a stricter compiler be less willing to let that go?

Comment: If you haven't manually installed gcc, that command will be aliased to clang.  A warning isn't 'letting it go'; it's telling you to fix it!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, to clarify:
OS X - Runs fine,
Linux - Gives warning, and doesn't work

Comment: Do you have the same version of GCC on both systems?

Comment: @Barmar, as predicted: no.

on Mac OS I have clang, and on Red Hat, i have gcc. It doesn't work on Red Hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C strings are terminated by NUL characters (byte value 0, usually written as `\0`). So you cannot put one in the middle of a string, which is what the second (completely correct) warning is telling you.

Since `scanf` will stop reading the format when it reaches the "end" -- that is, the `NUL` character -- the last `%[` format is not terminated correctly. That's the first warning.

It's possible that the `scanf` standard library function doesn't care about the missing terminator. It's likely that you are providing different compiler warning options on the two systems, or that the default warnings are different.

Either way, you should fix your code so that it doesn't give you those warnings.

Comment: I don't understand why this would fail on Linux, and run correctly on mac os.

Comment: @DerekHalden: In your question, you had it the other way around. Anyway, the two systems have different standard library implementations, and one might be more tolerant than the other one.

Comment: Also, is there something I could use instead of ^[\0] to get the entire rest of the string?

Comment: Sure, various different ways. The easiest one is `%99999c` (where you make sure the receiving string has at least 100000 characters). Use whatever value for 99999 seems convenient to you; just make sure that the receiver has that number of characters + 1 (for the NUL).

Comment: A more sensible solution would be to use the `%n` format indicator to get the current byte position inside the input string. That avoids the copy, and the possible buffer-overflow. You then know where the "rest of the string" starts, and you can do something appropriate, whatever that might be.